# Configure routes with post method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am creating a web service in rails application and I need to configure routes with respect to "books/CreateBookItem" with post method.

But since I will not have a view page for this to create a book item, for testing purpose I am typing the url in the browser as

```
localhost:3000/books/CreateBookItem
```

But now when I type the above url in browser it is taking as GET request.

So how do I configure the routes for the above.

Comment: if you want a post route, you would have to test it by issuing a post request. Automated tests with rspec or test::unit can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Add this createbookitem action to books resources in routes.rb:

```
resources books 
   collection do
     post :createbookitem 
   end  
end
```

Don't want to have any view for this action then create createbookitem action with disabled render.
   class BooksController < ApplicationController

```
def createbookitem
      #do your stuffs 
       render nothing: true
end
```

end